# javascript: select sentence in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, text-segmentation

I want to create a text annotation tool. Suppose we have some texts displayed like in the picture below, the objective effect is: after the user click on somewhere in the text, the whole sentence is automatically selected and highlighted.

[image]

I have no idea how to achieve that effects. Can someone points me either codes or resources that can solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You wanna select only one at time?

Comment: Yep. select only one sentence in a paragraph

Comment: Great, the last reply fits you perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/6gf25/1/

toggles one sentence at a time, hiding highlight from previously toggled sentences.

```
<div class="paragraph">
    <p class="sentence">Blah bdsfaflsdajflasdfslah blah,Yah Yahasdaflasdkfjasdlfjsdafasd Yah Nah. </p>
    <p class="sentence">Blasdfasdah bdsfaflsdajflasdfslah blah,Yah Yahasdlfjsdkaflasdkfjasdlfjsdafasd Yah, Nah NAh Nah. </p>
    <p class="sentence">Blah bdsfaflslajfdladajflasdfslah blah,Yah Yahasdlfjsdkaflasdkfjasdlfjsdafasd Yah, Nah NAh Nah. </p>
    <p class="sentence">Blah bdsfaflsdajflasdfslah blah,Yah Yahasdlfjsdkaflasdkfjasdlfjsdafasadsfasdd Yah, NadfasdfasdfaAh Nah. </p>
    <p class="sentence">Blah bdsfaflsdajflasdfslah blah,Yah Yahasdlfjsdkaflasdkfjasdlfjsdafasd Yah, Nah NAh Nah. </p>
    <p class="sentence">Blah bdsfaflsdajflasdfslah blah,Yah Yahasdlfjsdkaflasd Nah. </p>
    <p class="sentence">Blah bdsfaflsdajflasdfslah blah,Yah Yahasdlfjsdkaflasdkfjasdlfjsdafasd Yah, Nah NAh Nah. </p>
    <p class="sentence">Blah bdsfaflsdajflasdfslah blah,YaZAHah NAh Nah. </p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.sentence').click(function(){
        $('.highlight').toggleClass('highlight');
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.paragraph { width: 95%; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; background: #fff;}
.sentence { width: 100%; display: inline;}
.highlight{ background-color: #FC9A24}
-->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode (might actually work):

```
$(".class").click(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
});
```

and assign this class to all p tags

Answer (score 1):

if each of the sentences have a common class (say 'chat-sentence'), we could do it by,

```
$('.chat-sentence').click(function() {
    $(this).select(); 
});
```

A generic fn which works across all browsers is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you are new on this, so I'll explain some details:

Start getting [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) up and running in a minute or less:

Insert this into your HTML (most commonly in the head, but you can throw it before the end body tag too):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Then place a script element after your jQuery one.
It will toggle the Style of your sentences.

```
<script>
  $(function() { 
    $('.sentence').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('sentenceStyle');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now you need to apply the Styles ([CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS))

Placed a style element after your  tag:

```
<style>
  .sentenceStyle {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
```

Now you are ready to go! Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/3m22s/) in case your get confused.